# NSTimer's interrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Summary:** I'm developing an iOS app that requires login to an account hosted in a web application. The account is created and maintained in the web application (via a web interface, not the iOS app), and could be changed or deleted after the iOS app has started using the account. Therefore, I need to verify that the account is still active in the web application on a regular basis. I store the deviceID (a unique account number) in the iOS app using NSUserDefaults, and want to use this value with the hardware unique ID to confirm the iOS device is still associated with an active account.

**My Problem:** The NSTimers that keep the data fresh when the user is logged in stop working if I implement the verifyDeviceConfiguration method.

**More Detail:**
Login occurs within my WelcomeViewController, which uses a storyboardSegue to open the MainViewController which presents the content. This is an example of one of the NSTimers within the ViewDidLoad of my MainViewController:

```
getWeather = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600 target:self selector:@selector(startFetchingWeather:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Following is the code I implemented to verify the iOS device is still associated with a valid account. This is located in the WelcomeViewController:

```
-(void)verifyDeviceConfiguration:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [_uManager validateDevice:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"deviceID"] deviceNumber:[SKFunctions identifierForVendor1]];
}

-(void)didReceiveValidationConfirmation:(NSArray *)message
{   
    if([message count] == 1)
    {
        for (NSArray *currentMessage in message)
        {
            // fails to validate
            if([currentMessage valueForKey:@"loginError"] != nil)
            {
                // empty device and location
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"deviceID"];

            // request user pair the device again
            NSString *message = @"There was an error validating this device. Please pair the device again.";
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Validation Error" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView showWithCompletion:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex)
             {
                 [self viewDidAppear:YES];
             }];

        }
        // successfully validates
        else
        {
            // initiate the seque to the device display
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"registeredUserSegue" sender:nil];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"This should never happen");


  }
}

-(void)deviceValidationFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Device validation error");
}
```

And, there's code using NSURLConnection to get a response back from the server providing confirmation of the account. That code is as follows:

```
-(void)validateDevice:(NSNumber *)deviceID deviceNumber:(NSString *)deviceNumber
{
    [self.communicator validateDevice:deviceID deviceNumber:deviceNumber];
}

-(void)receivedValidationConfirmationJSON:(NSData *)objectNotation
{
    NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:objectNotation encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Decoded Validation Confirmation: %@", decodedString);

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *validationMessage = [SKLoginBuilder deviceValidationConfirmationJSON:objectNotation error:&error];

    if(error != nil) {
        [self.delegate deviceValidationFailedWithError:error];
    } else {
        [self.delegate didReceiveValidationConfirmation:validationMessage];
    }
}    

-(void)validateDevice:(NSNumber *)deviceID deviceNumber:(NSString *)deviceNumber
{
    NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@&d=%@&n=%@&apiKey=%@", API_URL, @"validation", deviceID, deviceNumber, API_KEY_LOGIN];
    NSLog(@"Device Validation URL: %@", urlAsString);

    BOOL validUrl = [SKFunctions validateURL:urlAsString];

    if(validUrl)
    {
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlAsString];

        if([NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString] != nil)
        {
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if(error) {
                    [self.delegate deviceValidationFailedWithError:error];
                } else {
                    [self.delegate receivedValidationConfirmationJSON:data];
                }
            }];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //error handing for poorly formatted url
        UIAlertView *urlFailure = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was an error validating your tablet. Please logout and login again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
        [urlFailure show];
        }
    }
```

If I turn verifyDeviceConfiguration off, everything works well...the NSTimers fire and the data is refreshed. If I turn verifyDeviceConfiguration on, the MainViewController will load, it will populate the data once (the initial load of the data is called directly, not using the NSTimers), and the NSTimers will not fire and refresh the data.

And, eventually, I'll take care of the NSLog statements.

Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am living and learning! I had been invalidating the timers as below following specific events and then trying to run the timers again.  Really what I wanted/needed was to pause the timer...which I understand can't be done. So, I've taken a different approach and all is well.

```
[getTime invalidate];
```

Thanks.